# Change hibernates behaviour on nullable = false and unique = true with oracle 10+

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, jpa-2.0

Since hibernate does not work correctly (in my opinion ;)) on fields with `@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)` and oracle DB, I want to change hibernates behaviour with this.

The problem is that only the unique constraint is applied but not the not null constraint which means that oracle can store one null value which can lead to errors in the application... I tried to pair it with @NotNull from hibernate validator (which also creates a not null constraint normally) but again paired up with the unique constraint its not working. Also a table level unique constraint overrides not null.

So since this seems to be a known problem I wonder there if there is no other fix then creating the missing constraints by hand.

Is there a viable option to "hijack" hibernates table creation/update process and generate that statement i.e with a custom made annotation? Should I just override the @Column annotation by my self?

Any suggestions? We don't want to maintain an sql script that just contains all not null constraints.